# How to best compose two cryptographic hashes?

Tags: cryptography, cryptographic-hash-function

Given two cryptographic hashes (e.g. using SHA1):

```
hash1 = sha1(data1)
hash2 = sha1(data2)
```

I would like to compose the two hashes into a value that "looks like" another hash (e.g. it is 160 bits for SHA1).  Assume that only `hash1` and `hash2` are known, and `data1` and `data2` are unknown.

**Option 1:** compute the hash of the concatenation of the two hashes:

```
hash3 = sha1(concat(hash1, hash2))
```

**Option 2:** compute the XOR of the two hashes:

```
hash3 = hash1 XOR hash2
```

Which option is less likely to have collisions?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about crypto, not programming.  Try crypto.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're concerned about hash collisions your best bet is to use a better hash algorithm, if possible (e.g. SHA-2 or SHA-3).

However, to answer your question: given two values, if you XOR them, you may see collisions even before you do the hashing.  For example, 1110 XOR 1111 is 0001, and 0011 XOR 0011 is also 0001.  On the other hand, concatenating the values can't introduce pre-hashing collisions.  So I'd concatenate.

Comment: It's worse than that.  Assume `data1 == data2` then in his example `hash1 == hash2` and `hash3 ==0`.  This is true any time the inputs match - infinite hash collisions for free.

Comment: Yeah, it leaks information about data1 & data2, something hashes should not do. If I'm not mistaken, hash trees also work with concatenation, you're basically building a hash tree with one node and two leafs.